# How to visualise seeded lda model using LDAvis in R?

Tags: r, lda, topic-modeling

I am using R seededlda package to train a seeded lda model.

`textmodel_seededlda(dfmt, dict, residual = TRUE)`

https://github.com/koheiw/seededlda

I was wondering if there is a way to visualise the model output using LDAvis package (https://github.com/cpsievert/LDAvis)?

Comment: Did you ever make progress on this?

Comment: I didn't, sorry. I ended up using different LDA algorithms in python and python version of LDAvis.

Answer (score 0):

I have just figured this out. The LDAvis package has a createJSON function, which allows you to generate a json object from the relevant outputs of your text model (as in the example shown below). The json object is then fed into the serVis function to generate the LDAvis plot. It has worked perfectly for me.

```
library(pacman)

p_load("seededlda",
       "quanteda",
       "LDAvis"
)

slda <- textmodel_seededlda(dfmt, dict, residual = TRUE)

json <- createJSON(phi = slda$phi, 
                    theta = slda$theta, 
                    doc.length = rowSums(dfmt), 
                    vocab = colnames(dfmt), 
                    term.frequency = colSums(dfmt)
)

serVis(json)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**